# can not active click event after animation of the view

Tags: android

this is the structure of my view

```
linearlayout  orientate = horizontal
    listview1
    listview2
    listview3
```

and I set listview1.start(animation)
but, after animation the click event can not work.but it will effect on its origin position.
I also

```
animation.setFillAfter(true)  animation.setFillEnable(true).
```

And, what's more I use the delegate to move the effective position. but failed.

```
for(int i = 0; i<mViews.size();i++){
        mViews.get(i).startAnimation(moveLeftAnimation);
        Rect rect = new Rect();
        mViews.get(i).getHitRect(rect);
        rect.left -= 413;
        rect.right -= 413;
        Log.e("filebrowser view move left", "rect left =  "+rect.left +" right = "+rect.right);
        setTouchDelegate(new TouchDelegate(rect, mViews.get(i)));
    }
```

mViews is a arraylist, which stores listview1 listview2 listview3.Can anyone help me.thanks for any help.

Comment: does it still work in the original place where you put it?

Comment: yes it still work in the original place

Comment: i met the same problem, and can't not find a solution~ i found that 1.when FrameLayout contains a lot of views, the last added view can response to the click.
2.when RelativeLayout contains a lot of views, none of the views can response to the click.

Comment: @Songzhw my problem is caused by animation, and your problems, first FrameLayout is absoluty that way.But I can not figure out why the relativeLayout works that way as you describe.