# Android - How to interact with a view after it has been animated?

Tags: android, android-animation

I have a view that is animated using [TranslateAnimation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html):

```
TranslateAnimation translateAnim = new TranslateAnimation(fromX, toX, fromY, toY);
translateAnim.setDuration(SLIDING_SPEED);
translateAnim.setInterpolator(new BounceInterpolator());
translateAnim.setFillAfter(true);
mSlidingView.startAnimation(translateAnim);
```

The animation works fine but after it's finished I can't click on the view anymore. Instead I can still click on its previous location.

I have searched for similar questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7743903/clicking-a-view-on-translate-animation), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7509206/can-not-active-click-event-after-animation-of-the-view) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9182893/android-unable-to-click-the-bottom-textview-after-translate-animation-within-a)) on StackOverflow but none of them provides any solution. I have heard that the [ObjectAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html#setPropertyName%28java.lang.String%29) fixed this, but is there anything I can do using the previous API? (I don't want to rely on yet another third party library like [NineOldAndroids](https://github.com/JakeWharton/NineOldAndroids) to support the new animation API on pre-honeycomb devices). Oh and I have tried to [invalidate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate%28%29) the view but it doesn't change anything.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I guess there is not link, but have you tried : 
(before setFillAfter)

```
translateAnim.setFillEnabled(true);
```

Comment: What viewGroup do you use ? ( I mean, in what kind of layout is your view translating ? )

Comment: hum, look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502580/view-still-there-but-not-visible-after-being-moved-out-by-animation)

Comment: As a workarround, you could set the new position of your view via setLayoutParams in the onAnimationEnd method of the animation listener. That's pretty dirty, but could fix the problem

Comment: Yes as a mentioned in my question, the guy is suggesting to use the new API but I don't want to (unless I **really** don't have the choice). Also the `SlidingDrawer` is not appropriate for what I want to achieve.

Comment: For your Workaround, could be a solution indeed. Let me try :)

Answer (score 0):

In **API 11+**, We can do that by **ObjectAnimator** class.

In **API 10-**, When we translate a view, the visual view will be translated, but the physical location still in the old location, changing the margin of the translated view after finish the animation could solve the problem.